# Disallow Java/Flash users - Why not working?

Tags: java, javascript, browser

So im trying to make a security page. This security page will check to see if Flash or Java is enabled, and if it is, it will lead a user to another page.

I first thought of using Javascript to achieve this but the results were not what I expected:

```
if (navigator.javaEnabled())
{
<?php header('Location: http://www.google.com/'); ?>
}
else
{
<?php header('Location: http://www.yahoo.com/'); ?>
}
```

I tried this within Chrome and Firefox and they always redirect to yahoo. I enabled the Java plug-in in Firefox (I had it disabled before this test) and restarted the browser, same results.

Its weird because before it always took me to google, even if Java was disabled. I just need a good way to detect if Java is allowed, I dont want to run any applet.

Ive been seeing around other people may have the same problem. I cant contact www.java.com because my host does not allow outbound connections.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to look into the differences between client side and server side languages.

Comment: Do you know http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/Java/ ?

Comment: And @John means that you're trying to execute PHP inside the browser. This is "too late" since the page has already been generated in PHP and served to your browser.

Comment: Why would you want to disable users with Java or Flash anyway?  Just don't use Java or Flash on your site...

Comment: On client side, in javascript. `if (navigator.javaEnabled()){ window.location = "http://google.com";}` is that what you which to do?

Comment: @Nils Thank you so much for your solution! Thanks to flup to (cant tag him, StackOverFlow wont let me tag more people)

Comment: @MoyleJack I wrote up the solution. Feel free to approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client side, in javascript, you can solve this. When you detect that java is enabled you can set `window.location` to redirect your user to another page.

```
if (navigator.javaEnabled()) {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
} else {
    window.location = "http://yahoo.com";
}
```

Comment: Lol thanks for posting this again so I could give you credit.